# Compare cell values csv file python

Tags: python, csv

I have the following dataset in a CSV file

[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 2]

Now I want to count each value by comparing them and store it in an array, but I don't want the frequency. So my output should be like this:

[3, 4, 3, 2, 1]

My code is as follows:

```
import csv

with open("c:/Users/Niels/Desktop/test.csv", 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=';')
    data = []

    for column in reader:
        data.append(column[0])

    results = data
    results = [int(i) for i in results]
    print results

    dataFiltered = []
    for i in results:
        if i == (i+1):
            counter = counter + 1
            dataFiltered.append(counter)
            counter = 0
    print dataFiltered
```

My idea was by comparing the cell values. I know something is wrong in the for loop of results, but I can't figure out where my mistake is. My idea was by comparing the cell values. Maybe

Comment: `if i == (i+1):` that cannot happen ! do you want to check if previous element is the same as the next one?

Comment: Why are you doing `results = data; results = [int(i) for i in results]`? Why not just do `results = [int(i) for i in data]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I won't go into the details of your loop which is *very* wrong, `if i==(i+1):` just cannot be `True` for starters.

Next, you'd be better off with [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) and sum the length of the groups:

```
import itertools

results = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 2]

freq = [len(list(v)) for _,v in itertools.groupby(results)]

print(freq)
```

`len(list(v))` uses `list` to force the iteration on the grouped items so we can compute the length (maybe `sum(1 for x in v)` would more performant/appropriate, I haven't benched both approaches)

I get:

```
[3, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Aside: reading the first column of a csv file and convert the result to integer can be simply acheived by:

```
results = [int(row[0]) for row in reader]
```